# How to migrate Azure MySql database to Azure MS SQL Database

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-sql-database, database-migration, azure-mysql-database

It's clear on how to migrate on-premise or RDS MySql database to Azure MS Sql, using [Data Migration Assistant for MySql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/mysql/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-mysql-mysqltosql?view=azuresqldb-current) or the azure [Database Migration Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/), but absolutely nothing for Azure MySql to Azure Sql.

What is the best way to migrate Azure MySql to Azure SQL database?

Only option so far is having to download my Azure MySql database to a local instance then use the Data Migration Assistant for MySql tool to upload to Azure SQL.

Comment: How about Data Factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is the best way you want, but I guess that you want migrate the database online and without client tools.

Maybe you could think about [Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction), it's always used to migrate the database. It can help us auto create the table and schema.

Please reference the tutorials below:

1. [Copy data to and from Azure Database for MySQL using Azure Data
   Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-database-for-mysql)
2. [Copy and transform data in Azure SQL Database by using Azure Data
   Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database)

The easiest way is that you can use [Copy data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-tool).

Follow these steps:

**Copy data tool:**
[image]

**Create new connection to Azure SQL Database for MySQL:**
[image]

**Select all tables in the Azure MySQL:**
[image]
[image]

**Create the Azure SQL database as Destination data store**:
[image]

**Table mapping, auto create:**
[image]

**Column mapping:**
[image]

Next run the copy tool step by step.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I looked into data factory but couldn't see how to achieve MySQL to MS SQL migration. Could you edit you answer to detail 'how'? cheers

Comment: Perfect thanks! I would add for the benefit of other that it's likely the mapped types will need changing to suit Sql Server.